# How to tidy my weekyear variable in the dataset

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset with a weekyear variable.
For example:

```
Weekyear
12016
22016
32016
...
422016
432016
442016
```

As you might understand this creates some difficulties as approaching this variable as an integer does not allow me to sort it descending-wise.

Therefore, I want to change variable from `12016` to `201601` to allow desc ordering. This would have been easy if my values would have the same number of characters, they aren't (for example `12016` and `432016`).

Does anyone know how to treat this variable? Thanks in advance!

Diederik

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the year and week using modulo arithmetic and integer division.

```
x <- 432016
year <- x %% 10000
week <- x %/% 10000
week <- sprintf("%02d", week) # make sure single digits have leading zeros
new_x <- paste0(year, week)
new_x <- as.integer(new_x) 
new_x
```

Answer (score 0):

Your could use `stringr::str_sub` to get the format you want:

```
# Getting the year
years <- stringr::str_sub(text, -4)

# Getting the weeks
weeks <- stringr::str_sub(text, end = nchar(text) - 4)
weeks <- ifelse(nchar(weeks) == 1, paste0(0, weeks), weeks)

as.integer(paste0(years, weeks))
[1] 201601 201602 201603 201642 201643 201644
```

**Data**:

```
text <- c(12016, 22016, 32016, 422016, 432016, 442016)
```

EDIT:
Or, you can use a combo of `str_pad` and `str_sub`:

```
library(stringr)

text_paded <- str_pad(text, 6, "left", 0)

as.integer(paste0(str_sub(text_paded, start = -4), str_sub(text_paded, end = 2)))
[1] 201601 201602 201603 201642 201643 201644
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very short approach using regex. No packages needed.
To better understand it, I split it in 2 steps but you can nest the calls.

```
text <- c(12016, 22016, 32016, 422016, 432016, 442016)

# first add a zero to weeks with one digit
text1 <- gsub("(\\b\\d{5}\\b)", "0\\1", text)

# then change position of first two and last four digits
gsub("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})", "\\2\\1", text1)
```